# Need help understanding "readonly" in C#

Tags: c#, collections, readonly

I'm trying to get my head around this. What's the difference between these 4?

```
 1. private ObservableCollection<T> _myObservableCollestionOfTs
 2. private readonly ObservableCollection<T> _myObservableCollestionOfTs
 3. private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> _myObservableCollestionOfTs
 4. private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> _myObservableCollestionOfTs
```

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 5):

1. **A mutable reference to a mutable collection.**  The collection's elements can be changed, and the reference pointing to the collection can be reassigned to a different collection or set to null.
2. **An immutable reference to a mutable collection.**  The collection's elements can be changed, but the reference pointing to the collection cannot.
3. **A mutable reference to an immutable collection.**  The collection's elements cannot be changed, but the reference can be pointed to a different collection.
4. **An immutable reference to an immutable collection.** Neither the collection's elements nor the reference pointing to the collection can be changed.

Read-only collections are simply wrapper classes around ordinary collections that prevent modification of the collection's elements; see the remarks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0).